# Objective -c : How to avoid a collision between two ball?

Tags: ios

I'm new here , 
I should programming a game with two balls the first is controlled by the user and the second should be programming .
I don't know how to ensure that the second ball prevents the ball from the user?
I am a intermediate.
Can you help me.
I have a code to change :`CGRect tableRect = self.view.bounds;
    CGRect enemyRect = self.enemy.frame;

```
if (CGRectGetMinX(enemyRect)<CGRectGetMinX(tableRect) ||
    CGRectGetMaxX(enemyRect)>CGRectGetMaxX(tableRect)) {
    playerValue++;
    playerlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", playerValue];
    enemylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", enemyValue];
    moveX = -moveX;

}
if (CGRectGetMinY(enemyRect)<CGRectGetMinY(tableRect) ||
    CGRectGetMaxY(enemyRect)>CGRectGetMaxY(tableRect)) {
    playerValue++;
    playerlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", playerValue];
    enemylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", enemyValue];
    moveY = -moveY;
}
CGPoint center = enemy.center;
center.x += moveX;
center.y += moveY;
enemy.center = center;
[self performSelector:@selector(move) withObject:nil afterDelay:timerIntervale];


if (CGRectIntersectsRect(enemyRect, player.frame)) {
    CGRect frame = [player frame];
    frame.origin.x = 137.0f;
    frame.origin.y = 326.0;
    [player setFrame:frame];

    CGRect frame2 = [enemy frame];
    frame2.origin.x = 137.0f;
    frame2.origin.y = 20.0;
    [enemy setFrame:frame2];
    enemyValue++;
    playerlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", playerValue];
    enemylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", enemyValue];

}`
```

I want know if I do change the code or add lines.
Thanks you very much for help me.

AddGame

Comment: have you look at any physical engine? like box2d and Chipmunk

Comment: No, because my game should be created with UIKit but you know a solution with chipmunk or Box2D ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enemy.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: But you really should look at OpenGL or some kind of physical engine, you'll save yourself time in the long run.

Comment: The answer is your answer : "enemy.userInteractionEnabled = NO;"

Comment: there's a little tick underneath the up vote/downvote thing, click that.